# How can I control the layout of an embedded <OBJECT>?

Tags: javascript, dom, object-tag

Page1.html has

```
<html><head>
</head>
<body>
[<span class="foo">span unchanged</span>]
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName('foo').item(0);
    var synth = '<object data="http://localhost/~bruceaxtens/Page2.html">Page2.html not found</object>';
    a.innerHTML = synth;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So there are square brackets which should enclose the text which will be handed back by Page2.html

Page2.html contains

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Hello World");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I get however is the "Hello World" at the top of the page and the brackets a couple of inches further down.

Is there any way of keeping the two together?

Comment: in your first example: the script tag belongs in either the <body> or <head> element.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Does it really make that much difference?

Comment: If you code to the standard, you wont have to wonder if the error is yours or if it's a browser compatibility issue. It also means you wont have to worry about your code breaking in the future.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Fair comment. Moved.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Makes no difference, however, in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself thus:

Instead of returning HTML and have issues with OBJECT handling in different browsers, hand back Javascript and execute it in the context of the client's DOM.